# How did Zia get her vulture amulet back?

Tags: rick-riordan, the-kane-chronicles

In *The Red Pyramid*, Zia Rashid's *shabti* uses her vulture amulet to fly into the pyramid. Later, she 'dies', and is revealed to be a shabti.

Fast forward: In *The Throne of Fire*, the real Zia is woken up. And later, either in TToF or *The Serpents Shadow* - she uses her vulture amulet.

**How does she get the amulet from the shabti?**

Answer (score 2):

I have always assumed it is one of two different things.

**Riptide style theory** - In the Percy Jackson books the sword Riptide always returns to Percy Jackson's pocket. As we are in the same universe I reckon the Egyptians might have a vulture amulet with similar powers. The magic could have been edited to temporarily return to the shabti until it dies when the amulet will return to its original owner.

**Two amulets** - There may have been two amulets, one with Zia and one with the shabti.